# How can I make tmux use my default shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux

On a new setup, tmux is using bash instead of my default (zsh).

How can I force it to use zsh?

Comment: figured it out. Can set the following in tmux config: set -g default-command /bin/zsh set -g default-shell /bin/zsh

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to set default-command if you've set default-shell.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

in `~/.tmux.conf` or `/etc/tmux.conf`. Works on Fedora.

You can reload the config with `<leader>: source-file <conf file>` e.g.

`<C-b>: source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

You would need to do it for every tmux instance. Otherwise you may restart tmux with `killall tmux; tmux`

Comment: If this doesn't work for you then make sure you've restart `tmux`. Seems obvious but took me a good hour to figure out!

Comment: BTW: Restarting tmux means `killall tmux; tmux`. Took me quite a while to figure out.

Comment: Configs could be reloaded without killing a server: `bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "  Config reloaded..".`

Comment: Or simply run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` from the command line.

Comment: @js-coder: to more cleanly kill your tmux server I'd recommend `tmux kill-server` instead.

Comment: not sure if it's just a newer version of tmux, but I never had to kill the tmux server or tmux itself. Once you set the option, it should work.

Comment: `killall` not working on zesty. I had to `pkill tmux`. The processes were named `'tmux: server'` and `'tmux: client'`.

Answer (score 59):

First, ensure your default shell is set properly to `zsh` by running this in your command line:

```
chsh -s $(`which zsh`) $USER
```

Placing the following in your *~/.tmux.conf* is a more robust option for any shell.

```
set-option -g default-shell $SHELL
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to set user shell (`chsh -s`) as tmux offers an option independent of that.

Comment: I thought it was more robust to use the $SHELL variable. But it adds an extra step and confusion so I do prefer the accepted answer.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. My zsh is not installed in /bin/zsh.

Comment: Is the double command substitution intended?

Answer (score 25):

For MacOS users, drop this line in the bottom of your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

After you add that, kill and restart your tmux server and all should work.

Comment: Er, is there any indication that re5et (the OP) is on a Mac, or has that wrapper program installed?

Comment: I think this answer only works for Mac OS X

Comment: `tmux kill-server` is the command to end all tmux servers

Comment: Although it wasn't the answer the OP asked for, I ended up in this thread and indeed I am on OS X, using this wrapper, and this is the solution I needed; so Thank You!

Comment: how does this differ from `set-option -g default-shell `? the above does not seem to work with the Fish shell.

Comment: Change `zsh` to `$SHELL` to make it work without hard-coding your shell.

Answer (score 13):

tmux appears to use the `SHELL` environment variable, so the following should work:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh tmux
```

or

```
env SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh tmux
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. It appears to be correct: a common problem is using a different shell for e.g. iTerm but leaving login shell as `/bin/bash` to ensure nothing non-iteractive breaks. iTerm will not set `$SHELL` to the new shell name (unsure why), and bash initialisation will set it to the login shell if unset at startup. tmux then uses this value if `default-shell` is not set explicitly.

Comment: Yeah.. maybe `env SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh tmux` is better?  (updated the answer).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to force tmux to use the same shell as specified in your environment variable, you could use:

```
# force SHELL ENV variable as shell
set-option -g default-shell ${SHELL}
```

in your `~/.tmux.conf` or `/etc/tmux.conf`.

To get the change to actually take effect, you may need to `tmux kill-server` and then `tmux` to restart tmux.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me (the tmux kill-server command)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

I had to write both

```
set -g default-shell  "/bin/bash"
```

and

```
set -g default-command "/bin/bash"
```

in my `~/.tmux.conf` — Dont forget to run the following commands to reload the tmux.conf:

```
tmux kill-server; tmux
```

---

Im am using `tmux -V` 2.6 under Ubuntu 18 in the gnome-shell emulator.

I also enhanced tmux with https://github.com/samoshkin/tmux-config. Check it out, it's really cool.

Answer (score 3):

Use `chsh(1)`:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh $USER
```

Comment: i already had this set, but tmux was ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

Add this into your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-command /usr/local/bin/fish
```

Answer (score 2):

Log-out and log-in again fixed my problem. When echoed `$SHELL` it was still `/bin/bash` but after log-out it was changed to `/usr/bin/zsh`

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to replace:

```
default-command "/usr/local/bin/fish"
default-shell "/usr/local/bin/fish"
```

with

```
set-option -g default-command "/usr/local/bin/fish"
set-option -g default-shell "/usr/local/bin/fish"
```

in `.tmux.conf`
and run command `tmux kill-server; tmux`

Comment: This is a duplicate of answer https://superuser.com/a/1370909/174140.

Comment: @john I've used `set-option -g` instead of `set -g`. different versions of tmux most probably

Comment: `set` is an alias for `set-option`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted it to force to use an custom .bashrc. The following should work for any shell. My new is .tmux-bashrc is just an copy of .bashrc , minus the ncal or cowsay, etc... The speed improvements are now apparent.

in ~/.tmux.conf

```
set-option -g default-shell $SHELL
set-option -g default-command "$SHELL --init-file .tmux-bashrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I use Arch Linux inside Windows WSL2 and I have done `chsh -s /bin/zsh $USER` and when entering `tmux` it would not correctly load zsh(show some errors e.g. `add-zsh-hook function definition file not found` and so on.
If I enter `zsh` manually again, everything works fine.
And I found that inside `~/.tmux.conf` add one line `set -g default-command /bin/zsh` should be the answer to fix this problem but I don't know why setting `default-shell` or setting `SHELL` variable was in vain.

FYI, [tmux(1) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html)