# tmux doesn't use default shell

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

My tmux started to behave in a strange way, briefly. 
Today I noticed that my tmux session does not start with a bash shell but instead it starts with ?(no idea).  What I can see is just a dollar $.
Then if I try to call bash with `bash` it returns

```
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force.
```

[image: tmux without bash]

I wanted to add a `default-shell` for tmux in the `~/.tmux.conf` file, but it doesn't exist and if I create it tmux seems not seeing it.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $0` ?

Comment: The output is `sh`

Answer (score 5):

Manual page of tmux state the default-shell option process:

`default-shell path
Specify the default shell. This is used as the login shell for new windows when the default-command option is set to empty, and must be the full path of the executable. When started tmux tries to set a default value from the first suitable of the SHELL environment variable, the shell returned by getpwuid(3), or /bin/sh This option should be configured when tmux is used as a login shell.`

To set the default shell of tmux to Bash in .tmux.conf file, you must write it as:
`set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"`

If you want to set your system default shell (not specifically bash) as `default-shell`, you can do `set-option -g default-shell $SHELL` in your .tmux.conf file. This requires that the `$SHELL` variable is correctly set, though.
See https://superuser.com/a/395161/325399